# Windows 10 graphics output to monitor black screen

Tags: windows-10, display

A co-worker tried to connect a windows 10 laptop to an external monitor. The monitor was never picked up in the first place and he right clicked on the home screen, went to graphics output and set it to "monitor". After doing so the laptop screen is now black, and obviously its not showing on the monitor either.

Is there a way to revert the graphics settings with a hotkey or something? If I reboot in safe mode, will it use original settings? How do I force reboot windows 10 into safe mode without having access to the start screen?

Comment: If you disconnect the external monitor the laptop should recognise this and turn the built-in LCD back on? Failing that you could try power cycling the laptop by pressing and holding the power button?

Comment: Does Win+P (possibly several times) do anything useful?